# Is a compound optically active if plane polarised light is deflected by an angle of n*(2π) angles?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, light

Is a compound optically active if plane polarised light is deflected by an angle of  n*(2π) angles(like 360°); as there won't be any deflection in the analyser of the polarimeter?

Comment: yes for $n\neq 0$, because compound does interact with light and causes optical rotation. The way to measure this would be to take several measurements at different concentrations.

Comment: Don't this mean that actual angle also depends upon concentration like specific rotation?

Comment: On concentration and path. It is analogical to Lambert-Beer law ( A=eps.c.l ).

Comment: @Poutnik Okay, I got it.Should I delete the question now?

Comment: @Shiva I would prefer that you don't delete it since I also didn't knew about it earlier. Let others also know about it.

Comment: I don't have time at the moment, but there's worth in an answer differentiating between observed and specific rotation ( https://pediaa.com/difference-between-optical-rotation-and-specific-rotation/ ) and throwing in a few formulae connecting them

Comment: related question https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/166327/124759

Comment: @IanBush Thanks, It wasn't related to my question but I got new things to learn.

Comment: The answer to your question was already provided as a comment to the answer in the link Ritil provided above.

Comment: @ron Yes, please tell what should I do. Feel free to delete it if required.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**

The actual rotation you observe in a polarimeter depends on several factors: the path length, the concentration (if in solution) and the specific amount of optical rotation caused by the compound.

If you observe the actual rotation at a single concentration you might observe no *apparent* effect because the rotation was 360°. But at a different concentration or a different path length with the same substance you *would* observe a rotation.

So it is pretty easy to avoid the mistake of assuming no rotation by simply taking more than one measurement while varying the other factors.