# Does no optical rotation always implies optical inactivity?

Tags: stereochemistry, homework, optical-properties

This question popped up in my mind in reference to this question,
[Is a compound optically active if plane polarised light is deflected by an angle of n*(2π) angles?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/166324/124759)

Suppose that I give a chemistry exam in future in which a question is asked like this,

> A pure organic compound(not a racemic mixture) was analysed once and it was found that that there was absolutely zero rotation of PPL when passed through it(not even slight rotation as in cryptochirality). This means that it must be an optically active compound.

Now there are two options whether the above statement is true or false. What will be the answer? Assume that the organic compound is pure ie it is not a mixture (not even a racemic mixture). Also assume that the enantiomers (if possible) are separable which means that there is nothing like amine inversion or any other similar mechanism through which enantiomers can interconvert into each other.

Though it might be quite intuitive that the answer should be false but think about the person who set this question. (It has quite often happened with me that even after having the correct logic, my answer is consider wrong by majority.)

Comment: The statement is false. This does not mean that. Maybe it does not mean the opposite either, but that's irrelevant.

Comment: Be reminded that Emil Fischer observed no rotation from arabitol derived by reduction  of (+)-arabinose but yet its borax complex did.

Comment: What is there to support? See Zhe's comment in @Mithoron link. For a reference, try: Emil Fischer's Discovery of the Configuration of Glucose. A Semicentennial Retrospect, C. S. Hudson, J. Chem. Educ. 1941, 18(8), 353-356; https://doi.org/10.1021/ed018p353

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now there are two options whether the above statement is true or false. What will be the answer?

I choose to *false*. We have two cases for no rotation of plane polarized light. One of the case is that the compound is optically inactive. And the other case is when the analyte is a [racemic mixture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racemic_mixture).

Wikipedia states that,

> A racemic mixture, or racemate, is one that has equal amounts of left- and right-handed enantiomers of a chiral molecule.

So the rotation of plane polarized light is a combined effect of nature of compound and nature of analyte. So no rotation *doesn't implies that the compound is optically active*.

Comment: Suppose that it is given that it is a pure compound and not a racemic mixture. Now what?

Comment: Your tag doesn't seem to fit with the content in the question. It might be a possibile duplicate of this one
https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/166324/is-a-compound-optically-active-if-plane-polarised-light-is-deflected-by-an-angle

Comment: I have already referred to this question in my question, since the question came after reading that only, but the difference from that post is that my question is regarding exam. What will I do if such a question comes in an exam?

Comment: You have not considered the case where the specific rotation of the optically active, non-racemic compound is 360° or a multiple thereof.  That is why the rotation must be measured at at least 2 concentrations (and\or path lengths).  If you experimentally measure a 0° rotation and then remeasure with the concentration reduced to 75%, you will experimentally observe a rotation of 270° if the specific rotation is actually 360°.  If the compound is optically inactive, then the rotation will remain 0°.

Comment: @Ritil Stack Exchange is a place to ask questions about chemistry. It's not a place to ask about answering techniques for exams. We can tell you facts. What you do with those facts in your exam is your business.